# How can Apache IoTDB query measurement point value without spelling out all layers of equipment name?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

If Apache IoTDB wants to query the data value of one measuring point, the name of each layer of equipment must be spelled in the query statement (for example root.vehicle.electric.speed.sensor1). I wonder if there is a way to simplify this query process since my measurement point ID is unique, so how can I query the value of this unique measurement point in a easier way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the data value of one measurement point in Apache IoTDB without writing out all layers, you can use ** to represent multiple layers of devices when writing the query statement, such as root.vehicle.**.sensor1. In IoTDB,  ** can represent  multi-layers, while * can represent one layer.

Comment: What about ***?